# View.js doesn't show images

Tags: jquery

The view.js plugin ([finegoodsmarket.com/view/](http://finegoodsmarket.com/view/)) isn't showing any images on my test site:

[davidthunander.se/wordpress/](http://davidthunander.se/wordpress/)

The viewer opens, but the images are hidden... Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please do your best to give an example of the underlying problem.  The see this link questions dont help others in the future.

Comment: might help using a dev version of view.js. Clicking left or right throws an error after opening an image

Comment: Off the top of my head, the only thing I can think of is, are the images in the right folder? You would need to post the code to see where the problem is.

Comment: Yep, I have checked the links to the images. You can see the code at the test site.